# Type or Vector for representing points\positions

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I have a series of points\positions that won't change.  Should I represent as Vector of ints or as a new type?

My preference at the moment is to go with vector:

```
doSomething(myVec[0], myVec[1] );
doSomethingElse(myVec[2], myVec[3] );
```

as opposed to:

```
doSomething( myType.getPos1(), myType.getPos2() );
doSomethingElse( myType.getPos3(), myType.getPos4() );
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does the 'series of points' reflect the mathematical vector concept?

Comment: No, actually, positions would be a more appropriate term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `stl`, I'd use `vector< pair<int,int> >` (or `vector< pair<double,double> >` if the points aren't integer).  It works great for points.

So then you could do something like this:

```
vector< pair<int,int> > points;
points.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
points.push_back(make_pair(2,2));
```

Comment: I'd prefer a struct or even better a class. Using a class would allow adding methods, i.e. for distance calculation (myPoint.DistanceTo(myOtherPoint);). Using a pair might work but it doesn't really tell for what it is used, what information is stored in it and what it might be usefull for.

Comment: I don't follow your argument, why doesn't pair<int,int> tell what information is stored in it? I mean, it's a pair of ints, how much clearer does it need to be? You could actually combine the use of both ideas, make a struct with pair<int,int> in it, then add other methods for calc'ing distance, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Its difficult to say with the given information. But with whatever information provided so far, I would prefer to write a `struct Point` with `x` and `y` co-ordinates and create a `vector` of the points.   This will give you the benefits of storing the objects in a standard container plus it will logically bind the data in a common structure so that you don't have to `vec[0],vec[1]` every time when you want a point. As a side note, if you are writing the class with `getPos` method I would certainly write `getPos(int index)` rather than `getPos1`, `getPos2` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Why not create an actual vector struct/class?

By vector I mean a mathematical vector. Typically vectors are used for points and positions. A bonus of this is that your code will be much more readable.

This is how games, graphics and other applications do it. Using a list for related data is not OO, and one of the reasons OOP exists.

Comment: Does it have to be OO? STL is not OO either.

Comment: @Eddy certainly not, however when you are faking OO concepts in a language that supports OOP, that is an issue.

Answer (score 3):

The IMHO optimal solution would be:

```
struct Point {
  int x, y;
};
```

[... somewhere else ...]

```
vector<Point> points();
```

(My C++ is rusty, might not be correct syntax)

Comment: I think this would be clearer in the code. Then if the OP need some kind of performances, 3D or I don't know which type of mathematical calculus, there are solutions as Finglas said.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate over them then the answer is obvious.

If they don't change and you can manage the complexity then the first option is fine. The second might be more readable (if you choose good names).

You can also write a class that contains or holds a reference to the vector. In that case you can have the benefits of both.

You could also use the Boost.tuple library.

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

boost::tuple<int,int,int,int> position;
```

and access them as:

```
position.get<N>(); // where N is in 1,2,3,4
```